# Incorrect syntax near 's'

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I get an error on `sc.ExecuteNonQuery();`.. Error: `Incorrect syntax near 's'`

Code:

```
con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DELL-PC;Initial Catalog=sashi;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Login VALUES('" + textBoxUID.Text + "','" + textBoxPWD.Text + "','" + comboBoxQUN.Text + "','" + textBoxANS.Text + "' ) ", con);

sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Record has been inserted");

con.Close();
```

What I forgot or where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Please Use Parameters like this:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DELL-PC;Initial Catalog=sashi;Integrated Security=True")) 
{
    con.Open(); 
    using(var sc = connection.CreateCommand()) 
    { 
        sc.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Login VALUES(@uid,@pass,@qun,@ans)";  

        sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@uid", textBoxUID.Text));
        sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pass", textBoxPWD.Text));
        sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@qun", comboBoxQUN.Text));
        sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ans", textBoxANS.Text));;  

        sc.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    } 
}
```

Sql parameters helps prevent SQL Injection attacks.. and ist easier to read.. 
Does your login table have only four columns?  otherwise you must also specify this in your insert-statement: `INSERT INTO (col1, col2 ....`

Comment: yes .. only 4 columns

Comment: now getting error ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: sorry my bad... i have corrected my answer